# Pause and Resume KafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

What I've to do is pause the `KafkaConsumer` if during message consuming an error is thrown.

This is what I wrote

```
@KafkaListener(...)
public void consume(
 @Header(KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER) KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer,
 @Payload String message) {
  
    try {
        //consumer message
    } catch(Exception e) {
        saveConsumer(consumer);
        consumer.pause();
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a REST service in order to resume the consumer

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/consumer")
class ConsumerRestController {
    @PostMapping("/resume")
    public void resume() {
        KafkaConsumer<String,String> consumer = getConsumer();
        if(consumer != null) {
            consumer.resume(consumer.paused());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I've two questions.
First question: When I call consumer.pause() from `@KafkaListener` annotated method what happens?
Consumer is immediately paused or I can receive other messages associated on other offset of same topic-partition.
For example, I have "message1" with offset 3 and "message2" with offset 4, "message1" cause an exception, what happens to "message2"? Is it consumed anyway?

Second question: Resuming the consumer from REST service give a `ConcurrentModificationException` because `KafkaConsumer` is not thread safe. So, how come I have to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Do not pause the consumer directly; pause the container instead.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", ...)
```

```java
@Autowired KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

...

registry.getListenerContainer("foo").pause();
```

The pause will take effect before the next poll; if you want to immediately pause (and not process the remaining records from the last poll), throw an exeption after pausing (assuming you are using the, now default, `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

Comment: Thanks. For resuming instead? I need to resume and seek the consumer according a custom logic.

Comment: However I do not fully understood what is the difference between pausing the container and pausing the consumer. What would happen if `KafkaListener` is configured in order to listen on two or more topic or consumers listen on different partitions? I would pause/resume only the consumer who cannot process correctly the message, not all consumers.

Comment: Resume the container using the endpoint registry, the same way; if you need to perform seeks before resuming your listener should extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#seek

Comment: `@KafkaListener` is `@Repeatable`; if you want to control the consumers independently, you should use multiple annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot help me. I cannot use multiple annotations. What I continue to not understand is why `KafkaConsumer` as that logic, I see the same thread can invoke its methods (a part `wakeup`). Doc says `KafkaConsumer` is not thread safe, but instead seems it not support multithreading at all.

Comment: That is just the way the kafka-clients `KafkaConsumer` works; the only way to achieve concurrency is by using multiple consumers; which is exactly what the container does via its `concurrency` property.